# How to show a different value for a field in a Symfony FormType

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

I have a Symfony FormType like this

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class MyType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
  {
    $builder
      ->add('name', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'Name',
        'required' => true,
        'disabled' => false,
     ]);
  }
}
```

when editing, this text type will be populated with a value from the DB. I would like to change the value in the field depending on some other condition, I tried this with no luck:

```
if($someValue !== null) {
  $builder
    ->get('name')->setData($someValue);
}
```

how can I show a different value in the form?

Answer (score 0):

**In your controller** where you render the form, try to do in this way:
my exemple here is a form for entity named category

```
$form = $this->createForm(CategoryType::class, $category);

if($someValue !== null) {
     $form->get('name')->setData($someValue);
}
```